# Android application Online and offline

Tags: android, mysql, performance

I have to create an android application which shows some reports and images in Recycler view using json volley request   it works when internet is available    i also need to show the once loaded data in recycler view when internet is not available  here is the code i used to select data when internet is available

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                    (Request.Method.GET, Config.DATA_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                String str = response.toString();

                                                               loading.hide();
                                JSONArray arr =     response.getJSONArray("Stock_Report");


                                parseData(arr);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            // now you have the array. in this array you have the jsonObjects
                            // iterate on this array using a for loop and parse like you did before
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

            //Creating request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
        }
```

please help me to find better solution to show this data when internet is not available also thanks in advance

Comment: Insert the data in SQLite and Show data in recyclerview from database.

Comment: @androidlab can you please give an example  i am not much familiar with SQLite thanks in advance